# Using Active Directory Membership Provider for Site Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider, adfs

I have an MVC site that I am in the process of converting from Forms to Federated Authentication.  I am able to connect to the ADFS server and verify authentication. However the site currently uses an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to verify the roles of the users as different roles permit different access.

I can not figure out how to populate the MembershipProvider so that I can user things such as this:

```
User.IsInRole(@"MY-ROLE")
```

and this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MY-ROLE")]
```

I have this snippet in my web.config which works for forms authentication but isn't working in my federated site:

```
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionProtection="Secure" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" connectionStringName="ADConn" connectionUsername="LotusLDAPUser" connectionPassword="LotusLDAPUser" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

I have read a lot of MSDN docs and am still having trouble so please don't just answer with a link to docs.  I would appreciated some sample code.

UPDATE:
I added a RoleProvider to my web.config.  The role provider was being used in the forms application version successfully, so I believe the values are correct I just missed adding it to the web.config of the federated version.  Here is what I have:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ADLibraryROLES" cookiePath="/" cookieTimeout="1440" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" createPersistentCookie="true" cookieProtection="All">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ADConn" connectionUsername="LotusLDAPUser" connectionPassword="LotusLDAPUser" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" type="MyNamespace.ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

It is still returning false for

```
User.IsInRole(@"MY-ROLE")
```

and

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MY-ROLE")]
```

For a user I know to my in "MY-ROLE"

Comment: You may need to provide the RoleManager provider in your web.config [AD Roles Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28546/Active-Directory-Roles-Provider)

Comment: updated question, moving in the right direction but not there yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't setting the Session Token Cookie.  In the forms authentication version I had the code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
```

When testing the Federated version I wasn't setting the authentication cookie, this line is needed:

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

Where token is a `SessionSecurityToken` created from my `Claim`.